# What does chown 999 mean?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, chown, ownership

I know what `chmod` (change mode) and what `chown` (change owner) do.

I also understand what the numbers mean after `chmod` do.

I was going through a [docker tutorial](https://youtu.be/-XzMfd4XQak?t=410) and I saw `chown 999` being used.

What does it mean and do?

Comment: check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418117/72456

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241769/9533909

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> who is the user 999? Is it just custom to him or a code used universally?

In Ubuntu and the Ubuntu family flavours, **the numeric user ID in live sessions is 999**. (The literal user ID is ubuntu, kubuntu, lubuntu ... xubuntu but in all these cases the numeric user ID is 999.)

When you boot from a USB drive, 'Try Ubuntu', you boot into a live session.

You can check with the command

```
grep 999 /etc/group
```

and you will find the user if you run a live session. Otherwise you will probably not find anything via that command.

The operating system used for the Docker tutorial is probably an installed system. And there seems to be a user ID with the numeric 999. It is possible to create such a user ID, but in an installed Ubuntu system there is no standard user with that numeric user ID.

Answer (score 0):

As specify in [chown man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chown.1.html)

> chown - change file owner and group
>
> This  manual page documents the GNU version of chown.  chown changes
>   the user and/or group
>          ownership of each given file.  If only an owner (**a user name or numeric user ID**) is given,
>          that  user  is made the owner of each given file, and the files' group is not changed.

It seems like at the example in the video, the instructor change the **owner** of the folder to be user-id `999`

For example, in my machine, using `gdm` user-id is `130` and user `logstash` user-id is `999`

> gdm:x:130:135:Gnome Display Manager:/var/lib/gdm3:/bin/false
>
> logstash:x:999:999:LogStash Service User:/usr/share/logstash:/usr/sbin/nologin

```
root# mkdir /tmp/a1
root# ll /tmp/a1
total 44
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jan 15 09:54 ./
drwxrwxrwt 27 root root 36864 Jan 15 09:54 ../
root# chown 130 /tmp/a1
root# ll /tmp/a1
total 44
drwxr-xr-x  2 gdm  root  4096 Jan 15 09:54 ./
drwxrwxrwt 27 root root 36864 Jan 15 09:54 ../

# grep 999 /etc/passwd
logstash:x:999:999:LogStash Service User:/usr/share/logstash:/usr/sbin/nologin
root# chown 999 /tmp/a1
root# ll /tmp/a1
total 44
drwxr-xr-x  2 logstash root  4096 Jan 15 09:54 ./
drwxrwxrwt 27 root     root 36864 Jan 15 09:54 ../
```

Comment: who is the user 999? Is it just custom to him or a code used universally?

Comment: @YulePale updated my answer, in my machine `logstash` has user-id `999`

Comment: UID 999 is possible, there are other posts on askubuntu referencing this UID, but it may be specific to each system.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013516 mentions UIDs below 1000 are reserved for system users, but there is no official list of what those users may be and POSIX apparently doesnt enforce UIDs either.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/q/4159910/3701431 even root user isn't POSIXly required.

Answer (score 0):

At first, he copies this file into each running mongo container:

The official ***mongo image*** (which he uses in the video for creating multiple mongo nodes) has a default user called mongodb and its UID is 999

If you simply run the below command:

`docker exec mongo_node_name bash -c "grep 999 /etc/passwd"`

you will get the following result: `mongodb:x:999:999::/home/mongodb:/bin/sh`

So he is giving the the mongodb user the ownership of ***auth key file***.

999 is not special in linux just a created user happens that it has an id of *999*